# Is $x^3-6xy+y^2=-108$ a regular submanifold but not a regular $k$-submanifold?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

My book is An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu. Let $S = \{x^3-6xy+y^2=-108\}$, and let "submanifold" and "$k$-submanifold" mean, respectively, "regular" and "regular $k$-submanifold".

As in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220878/a-manifold-with-boundary-has-dimension-at-least-1-if-it-has-a-dimension-and-if), we have that Tu's manifolds with or without boundaries do not necessarily have dimensions. **Do Tu's (regular) submanifolds, however, necessarily have dimensions?**

- Here is [Definition 9.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1beG.png) of (regular) submanifolds, which seems to have dimensions.
- But now consider [Problem 9.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PH3p.png): [The answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyLLX.png) given is all real numbers except $0$ and $-108$. A [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbJe0.png) given by Richard G. Ligo claims that the reason (or a reason) why $x^3-6xy+y^2=-108$ is not a (regular) submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ is that connected components do not have the same dimension.

[image]

I think we must have either that

1. Ligo's solution is wrong.
2. Tu's submanifolds **have** dimensions and so $S$ is not a submanifold (i.e. $k$-submanifold, in this case) of $\mathbb R^2$ because of the connected components and **no other reason**.
3. Tu's regular submanifolds **have** dimensions and so $S$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ because of the connected components, but there are **other** reasons why $S$ is not a $k$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.
4. Tu **intended** a definition that allows submanifolds to not have dimensions. However, $S$ is neither a submanifold nor a $k$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ for a **different reason**.
5. Tu **intended** a definition that allows submanifolds to not have dimensions **and should have allowed** $S$ to be a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ even though $S$ is not a $k$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$. Thus each nonzero $c$ gives a submanifold with or without uniform dimension (same dimension for each connected component), while $c=-108$ is the only nonzero value that gives submanifold without uniform dimension.

---

**Update**: I asked

> Hello Prof Tu, I replied on stackex, but anyway for your convenience: It's actually just that your answer excluded -108. I think you meant to exclude -108 for submanifold with uniform dimension (same dimension for each connected component) but to include -108 for submanifold with non-uniform dimension? ...,

and Prof Tu replied

> ...The critical values are 0 and -108, but the inverse image of -108 is a regular submanifold.  Your interpretation is correct...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, a manifold or a submanifold can have connected components of different dimensions, so the set in question is a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with one connected component of dimension $1$ and one connected component of dimension $0$.

Comment: But [your answer says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyLLX.png) $-108$ is excluded? I think you intended as in (5), Prof Tu?

Comment: Update: see update to question.